# Why is TypeScript losing type inference and defaulting to 'any' here?

Tags: typescript

I've been refactoring some of our React app in TypeScript and hit a roadblock which I had to work around with, in my opinion, a very ugly double type argument. Is this a bug in TypeScript or is there some type ambiguity that I'm missing that causes the callback parameter to default to type 'any'?

I've worked around it by hiding the original type into another type argument, which seemingly fixes the callback method inferring wrong type from the "extends string" condition.

Original code:

```
type Optional<TItem> = TItem extends string
  ? { get?: (item: TItem) => string }
  : { get: (item: TItem) => string };

type TItem = { hello: string } | string;

const obj: Optional<TItem> = {
  get: item => typeof item === 'string' ? item : item.hello
};
```

Output from `npx tsc` for original code (TypeScript 5.4.2):

```
error TS7006: Parameter 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.

18   get: item => typeof item === 'string' ? item : item.hello
```

Workaround:

```
type TItem = { hello: string } | string;

type Optional<TItem, TItemType> = TItemType extends string
  ? { get?: (item: TItem) => string }
  : { get: (item: TItem) => string };

const obj: Optional<TItem, TItem> = {
  get: item => typeof item === 'string' ? item : item.hello
};
```

Comment: Your `Optional` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) and thus `Optional<TItem>` is a *union* of objects, so `get` is a union of methods, and TS doesn't know how to contextually type those. Apparently you have no desire for` Optional` to be distributive, so you should disable that as described in the doc linked above, and as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wOK96w). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz That is exactly what I was missing and is a better solution. As I understand it the type now becomes `{ get?: (item: TItem) => string } | { get: (item: TItem) => string }` when not distributive, which works fine for my use case.
I still don't understand why the original code, which I assume becomes `{ get?: (item: string) => string } | { get: (item: { hello: string }) => string }`, can't infer the callback argument type as `string | { hello: string }` for the callback implementation in `obj` though, especially as it can infer `string & { hello: string }` as the type when invoking it.

Comment: Hi. So personally, my suggestion is to try to use "infer". The thing is, sometimes even "infer" won't do the job. I think this form of type inferences is a bit of a "missing feature" in typescript which I hope Microsoft adds in the future. Either way, my suggestion is to attempt to formulate an answer that involves the "infer" keyword in it. Beware though, you will have to use an "any" in the more broad type, so be ready to make an eslint-disable comment.

Comment: Unless a union is a *discriminated* union you're not going to get that sort of inference. This is essentially [ms/TS#48460](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48460). It's not clear whether the "right" thing is `string | {hello: string}` or `{string & {hello: string}}` and frankly it's weird enough to have unions of functions that asking people to annotate the types themselves is a reasonable approach, instead of some inference that makes some percentage of people unhappy.  So, shall I write up the answer?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, yes you can write up an anwser. I understand that it's a very niche case anyway, even though I'm pretty sure the type should be an `&` union since the callback can be either type, therefore it's parameter needs to satisfy both "constraints" in case its passed to either of it's options, from the github link it's clear that there's never been a reason to implement that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original `Optional<T>` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), meaning that if `T` is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), then so is `Optional<T>`. But that becomes a union of objects, which means `get` is a union of methods, which means the `item` method parameter is... well, it's not clear. Right now, unions of methods that are not part of [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) have no [contextual type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) for their method parameters.  There was an issue filed at [microsoft/TypeScript#48460](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48460) asking for better contextual typing, but it was closed as working as intended. [A comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48460#issuecomment-1081014485) asks whether the contextual type should be a union or an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) or something else. Maybe you have an opinion about that, but the TS team doesn't think it's clear and doesn't want to spend energy working on it.

So, if you are committed to having a union of methods, you'll need to manually [annotate the parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#parameter-type-annotations) and be explicit about what type you expect it to have.

---

But it doesn't look like you really want a union. Instead for

```
type TItem = { hello: string } | string;
```

you want `Optional<TItem>` to evaluate to the single object type `{get: (item: TItem) => string}`, right? If so then all we need to do is disable the distributive object type by using the wrap-as-a-single-element-[tuple-type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) technique mentioned in the documentation for distributive conditional types:

```
type Optional<T> = [T] extends [string]
  ? { get?: (item: T) => string }
  : { get: (item: T) => string };
```

Now `Optional<T>` will never split `T` into union pieces before operating on it. And now you get the contextual type you were looking for:

```
const obj: Optional<TItem> = {
  get: item => typeof item === 'string' ? item : item.hello // okay
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwDwBUB8UAvFANo4C6UEAHsBCgCYDOpTwATgigObkBQUKAH4oAbyjcIwIQC4oACgR0AtnJwBKIgTaceUAL4Coc8ZOBzFKtZsLaOXbgYDcfPqEhQcASRVExUAAsIDAwkOR0HAygAHygInhdXAGNUNigkACMAKzk4RFRMXB8IZQJiUSMzOSUSrSh3CCQAMyga5SJCYgByeO4u4VbfapUAOiCQpD59FyA)